# IOException EBADF (Bad file descriptor) when reading large text files using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT in Release APK

Tags: java, android, ioexception

In my android app I provide a menu to import a text file (it contains some Json data that I process later using gson) via Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. These files can be large, 5 MB or more.

The problem: Everything works when I directly start the app from Android Studio on my phone, also for large files. Yet for the release apk I obtain an IOException EBADF (Bad file descriptor) if the files are larger than around 500kb (the exception is thrown by readLine). This is the case if I read the file from google drive or from Downloads.

I read the code using the following methods (called from my Activity):

```
private void importCollection() {
    // Fetch text file
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_COLLECTION_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        if (requestCode == IMPORT_COLLECTION_CODE) {
            // Fetch elements
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().
                        openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                        new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pfd.getFileDescriptor()));

                String line;

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) { // <-- Exception here
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }

                // ... do something with sb
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(bufferedReader != null) {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to put the code that reads the file into an AsyncTask (which is anyways a good idea), and to pass the FileReader to gson's fromJson-method directly, but I still obtain the same error.

There are some similar cases reported on StackOverflow in which people accidentially close the reader before they read more data, yet this is not the case in my code.

My obvious question: Does someone have an idea why this happens and/or a workaround?

Comment: Why dont you just open an InputStream instead of using a file descripter?

Comment: That is an excellent question to which I don't have an answer. Gonna try that. Thanks.

Comment: That actually solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

greenapps answered my question in the comment: [Following the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) I should have used an InputStream:

```
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        inputStream));
```

Then it works perfectly fine.